# Cadastro de dependente pegando ID do respectivo funcionário com laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, crud

Meu problema é que ao cadastrar um novo dependente o input, que possui o ID do funcionário o qual o dependente estará relacionado, seja automaticamente preenchido com o ID do usuário determinado e não que a pessoa que esteja cadastrando tenha que digitar o id do funcionário.

Para ser mais específico, já possuo o campo onde exibe a lista de dependentes de um determinado funcionário. Só gostaria de poder criar o novo dependente já pegando o id dele no campo.

Segue abaixo os códigos:

A view do formulário de criação do dependente:

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Dependentes
                    <a class="pull-right" href="{{url('dependentes
                                                ')}}">Lista de Dependentes</a>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">

                        @if(count($errors) > 0)
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                <ul>
                                    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                                        <li> {{$error}} </li>
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        @endif

                        @if(Session::has("msg_sucesso"))
                            <div class="alert alert-success"> {{ Session::get('msg_sucesso')}} </div>

                        @elseif(Session::has('msg_erro'))
                            <div class="alert alert-danger"> {{Session::get('msg_erro')}} </div>

                        @endif


                        @if(Request::is('*/editar'))
                            {!! Form::model($dependente, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'url' => 'dependentes/'.$dependente->id]) !!}
                        @else
                            {!! Form::open(['url' => 'dependentes/salvarDpt']) !!}
                        @endif 

                        {!! Form::label('funcionario_id', 'ID: ') !!}
                        {!! Form::input('text', 'funcionario_id', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'autofocus']) !!}
                        <br>
                        {!! Form::label('nome', 'Nome: ') !!}
                        {!! Form::input('text', 'nome', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'autofocus', 'placeholder' => 'Nome']) !!}   
                        <br>
                        {!! Form::label('dataNascimento', 'Data: ') !!}
                        {!! Form::input('date', 'dataNascimento', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'autofocus', 'placeholder' => 'AAAA-MM-DD']) !!}
                        <br>
                        {!! Form::submit('Salvar', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}

                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

O controller do dependente:

```
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\ValidarDepRequest;
use App\Dependente;

use Redirect;

use App\Funcionario;

class DependentesController extends Controller{

    public function index(){

        $dependentes = Dependente::get();
        return view('dependentes\lista', ['dependentes' => $dependentes]);

    }

    public function novoForm(){

        return view('dependentes.formDpt' );
    }

    public function salvar(ValidarDepRequest $request){

        $dependente = new Dependente();

        try{

            $dependente->create($request->all());

            \Session::flash('msg_sucesso', 'Dependente cadastrado!');

        } catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){

            var_dump($e->errorInfo);

            \Session::flash('msg_erro', 'ID do funcionário não existe!');

        }

        return Redirect::to('dependentes/formDpt');
    }

    public function editar($id){

        $dependente = Dependente::findOrFail($id);

        return view('dependentes.formDpt', ['dependente' => $dependente]);
    }

    public function atualizar($id, ValidarDepRequest $request){

        $dependente = Dependente::findOrFail($id);
        $dependente -> update($request->all());

        \Session::flash('msg_sucesso', 'Funcionário atualizado!');

        return Redirect::to('dependentes/'.$dependente->id.'/editarDpt');
    }

    public function deletar($id){

        $dependente = Dependente::findOrFail($id);
        $dependente -> delete();

        \Session::flash('msg_sucesso', 'Dependente deletado!');

        return Redirect::to('dependentes');

    }


}
```

E as rotas:

```
   Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::auth();

Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('funcionarios', 'FuncionariosController@index');
Route::get('funcionarios/novoForm', 'FuncionariosController@novoForm');
Route::get('funcionarios/{funcionario}/editar', 'FuncionariosController@editar');
Route::post('funcionarios/salvarFuncionario', 'FuncionariosController@salvarFuncionario');
Route::patch('funcionarios/{funcionario}', 'FuncionariosController@atualizar');
Route::delete('funcionarios/{funcionario}', 'FuncionariosController@deletar');


Route::get('dependentes', 'DependentesController@index');
Route::get('dependentes/formDpt', 'DependentesController@novoForm');
Route::post('dependentes/salvarDpt', 'DependentesController@salvar');
Route::delete('dependentes/{dependente}', 'DependentesController@deletar');
Route::get('dependentes/{dependente}/editarDpt', 'DependentesController@editar');
Route::patch('dependentes/{dependente}', 'DependentesController@atualizar');


Route::get('funcionarios/{funcionario}/listarDpt', 'FuncionariosController@listarDpt');

Route::get('funcionarios/{funcionario}/listarDpt', 'FuncionariosController@listarDpt');


Route::get('projetos', 'ProjetosController@index');
Route::get('projetos/novoForm', 'ProjetosController@novoForm');
Route::post('projetos/salvarProjeto', 'ProjetosController@salvarProjeto');
Route::get('projeto/projetos/edit', 'ProjetosController@edit');
```

Testei várias coisas, uma delas é, na view, trocar o valor null (no input do ID) por uma variável funcionário pegando sua ID, mas dá sempre erro variável não declarada.

Answer (score 3):

Eu tenho uma idéia do que poderia ser feito. Só não tenho como testar aqui na minha máquina.

Passe o id do funcionário na rota do novo form:

```
Route::get('dependentes/formDpt/{id?}', 'DependentesController@novoForm');
```

Modifique a action novoForm, no controller de dependentes, para receber o id do funcionário:

```
public function novoForm($id = null){
    $funcionario_id = ($id != null)?$id:0;

    return view('dependentes.formDpt', compact('funcionario_id') );
}
```

Por fim coloque o funcionario_id como hidden na sua view:

```
{!! Form::hidden('funcionario_id', isset($funcionario_id)?$funcionario_id:0) !!}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Infelizmente não funcionou.

Comment: Qual foi o erro que deu?

Answer (score 1):

O problema era a a variável que estava sendo instanciada erroneamente. Agradeço pela ajuda!